# Enable and Disable input field in ionic

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, user-interface, ionic-framework

I have an input field 
`<input type="text" ng-model="setting.email_id" placeholder="Email Id" class="inputBox">`.

I have an icon for edit next to this field :
`<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o editzoom" ng-click="editEmail()"></i>`

I want to the input field to be in disabled state and only when this icon is clicked, i want to enable the input field.

How do u achieve this in ionic framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="setting.email_id" placeholder="Email Id" class="inputBox" ng-disabled="!editEmail">

<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o editzoom" ng-click="editEmail()"></i>

$scope.editEmail = false;

editEmail(){
   $scope.editEmail = true;
}
```

Comment: This worked!. but i resolved it by changing the image into a button.